# Opencv-python cannot write video file

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to save a video file with opencv3 in python. The video that I want to save comes from another video file which I modify for tracking purposes. What I get is an empty .avi file, and I don't understand why. 
If it helps, I'm on OSX.
Thanks for the help.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Vid.avi')

width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (width-110, heigh-210))


while (cap.isOpened()):

    success, frame = cap.read()

    if success:

        hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame,lower,upper) #lower and upper are defined in another part of the code
        hsv_res = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv_frame,hsv_frame, mask= mask)



        out.write(hsv_res)
        cv2.imshow('Video', hsv_res)


        if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You've to manually resize your frame to the size you provided to the `VideoWriter` object.

Comment: Oh thanks, I actually did this but didn't write it here. The right code is the following:  
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame[210:,110:],cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV).
 

I think I have found the problem though, it comes from the fact that I want to turn the frame into gray scale. Basically the frame in hsv is well saved in the video, but not when I convert it to gray scale. any idea why ?

Comment: Please actually post the code that is giving you the problem so that a suitable answer can be provided. `VideoWriter` only supports three-channel images unless you're on Windows, in which case an optional flag `isColor=0` can allow grayscale video writing. From the [`VideoWriter()` docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html?highlight=videowriter#videowriter): "**isColor** – If it is not zero, the encoder will expect and encode color frames, otherwise it will work with grayscale frames (the flag is currently supported on Windows only)."